# How to judge one liners without knowledge of that area?

Tags: discussion

While doing reviews, many times I come across questions/answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037164/how-to-protect-my-phonegap-html-and-js-files-for-android-app) which looks like a one liner not making much sense to me since I don't understand the intricacies of Android development and many more other technologies for that matter and I end up flagging them as a low quality post without really having any idea about its quality.

It may be a sensible or a useful question for some users. But for me it is just a one liner which is not thought through much and posted in a haste by an inexperienced SE user. Is my approach right? Or the correct way of handling this scenario is googling away until I find some meaning out of that one liner and then decide if its low quality or not. Obviously the second option requires tons of time and patience which I dont have most of the time!!!

Comment: If you don't know it, don't flag it.

Comment: If you don't know how to judge something, skip it. Someone else will pick it up. Don't flag/review unless you know what you are doing, please.

Comment: Is the "Skip" button missing from your screen? It is designed for this circumstance.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip

Comment: I agree with the above comments. But, I can't think of a situation where a one-line question is good. It obviously won't show any attempt at the problem or any research effort which, IMHO, every question should have at least one or the other.

Comment: yes I can Skip it, but what I want to know is don't one liners fit in the low quality content category? so if I see a one liner outside of my area, shudn't I go ahead and flag it.

Comment: @Neels, that decision is on a post-by-post basis. Not all "one liners" are bad questions. I'll get you some raw numbers in a second

Comment: @Neels, [here is a query showing the highest scored one-liner questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/198957/257616/highest-scored-one-liner-questions). I'll agree that most of them are very old though. But I don't think it's a fact that all new one-liner questions are bad. It's just _most_ of them are bad.

Comment: ok..so i guess I have to go with my intuition.. Skip, Flag or Let it be..choice wont be easy!

Comment: Ok, show me one example of a up to standard one-liner question on Stack Overflow? **downvote and close**

Comment: [*"Learn to love that Skip button"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/165773 "quote source")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Very** Low Quality flag isn't just for posts that aren't up to the site's standards.  It's for posts that are completely unsalvagable, aren't real questions/answers at all, and just need to be deleted right away.  It's not a flag that should be used for just run of the mill "not good enough" posts.

Being short is a pretty strong sign that a given post isn't up to the site's standards (although this isn't *necessarily* the case).  It's a sign that the post may warrant downvotes.

The fact that a post is short isn't reason to flag it as Very Low Quality.  As there is no corresponding deletion reason in the Very Low Quality review queue for deleting a post just because it's "too short" the only thing for the queue to do is to do nothing.  This means that flagging these posts are consuming the time of a number of reviewers without ever accomplishing anything.

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted to hear. The reason for this dilemma itself was the same thought, whether I am doing injustice to someone due to the strong commitment towards site's standards and not because I did not know what a 'Skip' button does.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't understand the topic, you should skip.  Let somebody else make the call.

Comment: He's asking whether or not he should be flagging the posts, not what to do in the queue.  Additionally, no knowledge of the subject area is really needed to evaluate posts in the VLQ queue.

Comment: @Servy - no, that's simply not true.  I frequently see concise, useful one-line answers mistakenly downvoted or flagged by those too ignorant of the topic to realize that they are precisely the useful and accurate solution which is needed.  The skip button (or its move-along equivalent outside the queue) is indeed the correct response to something one lacks the knowledge to evaluate.  Incidentally, the worst cases are when the answer from the person who asked the question, stating their actual resolution, gets ignorantly deleted - leaving the question permanently orphaned.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Downvoting is not an action that can be taken from the VLQ queue.  You must be thinking of the first/last post queues, which are *entirely* different.  The VLQ posts queue is for deleting answers that are so completely terrible and unrecoverable that they need to be deleted.  The *only* actions that can be taken from the VLQ queue is to delete or not delete.  None of the reasons for deletion in the VLQ queue require understanding the topic at hand.  And once again, **this question is about whether or not to flag, not what to do in the queue**.

Comment: I'm not talking primarily about downvoting (though that can be a problem too), but rather about close/delete flags and votes - this is precisely where action by those **ignorant of the subject matter** vandalizes the site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You're comment *specifically* claimed that you were talking about downvotes, "Useful one-line answers mistakenly downvoted or flagged by those too ignorant of the topic."  The technical correctness of an answer is *irrelevant* when determining whether or not to delete it from the VLQ queue.  Whether the post has technical inaccuracies or not has exactly *zero* bearing on whether or not it should be deleted from the queue.  Posts should be deleted because they're not answers, rather comments on another answer, or a link only answer, or asking a new question, etc.

Comment: The idea that it's better to have *no answer at all* than to have a useful, accurate, relevant one that consists mostly of a link to an external resource, is the perfect of example of what's wrong with curating the site for *appearances* instead of *utility*.  It's the perfect of example of why people **should not be making judgement calls outside of their areas of knoweldge**. Removing helpful answers constitutes site vandalism, plain and simple - and if that's something you can't see, you need to take a break from things here until you have regained the perspective of a *software developer*.

Answer (score 2):

This was somewhat hidden in your question:

> flagging them as a low quality post without really having any idea about its quality.

Read that a couple times, just that.

The flag is not "I identified a post which has metrics suggestive of low quality and therefore needs attention from a domain expert."  Diamond moderators are not universal domain experts.  Most users using the review queues are not experts in the question domain.  You are making a claim about the quality, although you admit you have don't have *any idea about the quality*.